# Google API Update File Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

So...i am trying to use the update feature inside Visual Basic to update a files contents and metadata. Use the first piece of code to call it. However the code runs but does not update the file inside my drive and gives 0 errors. I am not sure what is wrong with the code since i have another piece of code which updates just the metadata just fine. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 bob.updateFile(bob.service, "0Bzqp8R7eFke2aHZqZHdYZ2RpYjg", "listbox.txt", "Test #2", ".txt", "meme.txt ", True)



 Public Function updateFile(service As DriveService, fileId As String, newTitle As String, newDescription As String, newMimeType As String, newFilename As String, newRevision As Boolean) As File
            Try
                ' First retrieve the file from the API.
                Dim file As File = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute
                ' File's new metadata.
                file.Title = newTitle
                file.Description = newDescription
                file.MimeType = newMimeType

                ' File's new content.
                Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFilename)
                Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
                'Send the request to the API.
                Dim request As FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload = service.Files.Update(file, fileId, stream, newMimeType)
                request.NewRevision = newRevision
                request.Upload()

                Dim updatedFile As File = request.ResponseBody
                Return updatedFile
                stream.Close()

            Catch e As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(("An error occurred: " + e.Message))
            End Try
        End Function
```

====

This is the working code for the metadata

```
 Public Function updateMetadata(ByVal service As DriveService, ByVal fileId As String, ByVal newTitle As String, ByVal newDescription As String, ByVal newMimeType As String, ByVal newRevision As Boolean) As File
        Try
            ' First retrieve the file from the API.
            Dim file As File = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute
            file.Title = newTitle
            file.Description = newDescription
            file.MimeType = newMimeType
            ' Update the file's metadata.
            Dim request As FilesResource.UpdateRequest = service.Files.Update(file, fileId)
            request.NewRevision = newRevision
            Dim updatedFile As File = request.Execute
            Return updatedFile

        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(("An error occurred: " + e.Message))
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: There is no VBA there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help!

Heres the working code, the issue was the mime type doesn't have to be changed!

```
bob.updateFile(bob.service, "0Bzqp8R7eFke2aHZqZHdYZ2RpYjg", "listbox.txt", "Test #2", ".txt", "meme.txt ", True)



 Public Function updateFile(service As DriveService, fileId As String, newTitle As String, newDescription As String, newMimeType As String, newFilename As String, newRevision As Boolean) As File
            Try
                ' First retrieve the file from the API.
                Dim file As File = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute
                ' File's new metadata.
                file.Title = newTitle
                file.Description = newDescription
                'file.MimeType = newMimeType

                ' File's new content.
                Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFilename)
                Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
                'Send the request to the API.
                Dim request As FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload = service.Files.Update(file, fileId, stream, newMimeType)
                request.NewRevision = newRevision
                request.Upload()

                Dim updatedFile As File = request.ResponseBody
                Return updatedFile
                stream.Close()

            Catch e As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(("An error occurred: " + e.Message))
            End Try
        End Function
```